# use zend framework 2/3 component's outside zf app

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am trying to use some zend framework components outside of zend framework but I am unable to do so.

Here is my composer file.

```
{
  "require": {
      "zendframework/zend-authentication": "^2.5.3"
   },
   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
          "Zend\\Authentication\\": ""
       }
   }
}
```

I was able to run composer update and install which has generated the autoload.php.

But when I try to use a the component I get "Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session' not found"

```
$session = new \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session();
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing from my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to require the autoloader

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

problem now solved