# Yii2 basic use Zend Framework 1 library

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, yii2, zend-search-lucene

I have successfully using Zend Framework 1 library in CodeIgniter

This is how I do it

1. copy the folder Zend in Zend framework's path/library
2. paste in CodeIgniter's system/libraries
3. in CodeIgniter's system/libraries, add Zend.php with this content

   ```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Zend {  
     function __construct($class = NULL) {   
     // include path for Zend Framework   
     // alter it accordingly if you have put the 'Zend' folder elsewhere

     ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . FCPATH . 'system/libraries');
       if ($class) {
         require_once (string) $class . EXT;
         log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
       } else {    
         log_message('debug', "Zend Class Initialized");
       }  
     }

     function load($class) {   
       require_once (string) $class . EXT;        
       log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");  
     }
   }
   ```
4. This is example how I use it in CodeIgniter's controller

   ```
   //load it inside function __construct()
   $this->load->library('Zend');
   $this->zend->load('Zend/Feed');
   $this->zend->load('Zend/Search/Lucene');

   //use it inside function
   $index = new Zend_Search_Lucene( "assets/index" );
   query = "yes";
   $hits = $index->find($query);
   ```

Now, I want to use Zend Framework 1 library in Yii2 basic

I have copied the folder Zend in Zend framework's path/library

Pasted it to Yii2 basic path/vendor folder

How to set and use Zend Framework 1 library in Yii2 basic?

Brief explanation appreciated! Thanks before

Comment: Never mess with system directory of CI. That's why is `APPPATH.'libraries/'` location for. More important, NEVER mess with vendor directory. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070396/use-zend-framework-2-3-components-outside-zf-app) how it is used correctly.

Comment: your example is for zend framework 2 @Tpojka

Comment: Try to use it the same way. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: can you give a brief example? i beginner in yii2 @Tpojka

Comment: Learn basic use of composer and including classes when composer is used. Start from that link guy asked and answered to himself.

Comment: im not use composer to that library @Tpojka

Comment: Or just do it like it should be, by adding Yii2 components [Yii2 search lucene](https://github.com/sadovojav/yii2-search-lucene). Or EVEN more, your ZEND library as component to Yii2 [HERE](https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-search-component-v2)

Comment: As long as there is vendor directory (and there is in Yii) you are using it basically. Yii does. Check composer docs. Using PHP without it is pointless as much as not using git.

Comment: Also, Zend 1 ended it's life almost year and a half ago.

Comment: never done that but maybe these [link1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/505/integrating-zf2-into-yii-use-case-demonstrated/) and [link2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration) might help you